# Property of a transport equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N, N=2$ or $N=3$ be a bounded smooth domain, $T>0$ and $y=y(x,t)\in L^{\infty}(\Omega\times (0,T))^N$ is a given vector function such that $\nabla\cdot y=0$. Consider the tranform equation

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\nabla\cdot (yu)=f(x,t), \mbox{for }(x,t)\in \Omega\times (0,T);\\ u_{t=0}=u_0, \ x\in \Omega.$$
How about the existence and regularity of solution of this transport equation?

For example, we need $u\in L^2(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega)),$ then what are $f$ and $u_0$?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the transport vector do not have enough regularity. 
look at these papers
Transport equation and Cauchy problem for BV vector fields by Luigi Ambrosio
and
ODEs,transport theory,and Sobolev spaces Diperna&P.Lions
Also their results do not give so strong results,only $L^{\infty}(0,T,L^p)$ when the transport vector is in certain Sobolev spaces.

Comment: If you could provide links to those papers and fix the writing of this post so that it is more easily readable, we would appreciate it.